# Problems reading .gct file into R

Tags: r, read.table

I downloaded a dataset from: https://gtexportal.org/home/datasets. File: GTEx_Analysis_2017-06-05_v8_RNASeQCv1.1.9_gene_reads.gct.gz. I also installed CePa in to R version 3.6. However, read.gct still is not found. I then tried this:

```
Data<-read.table("C:/Users/Highf_000/Desktop/GTEx_Analysis_2017-06-05_v8_RNASeQCv1.1.9_gene_reads.gct")
Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  : 
  line 1 did not have 17384 elements
```

Does anyone have a solution to this? I have never worked with a gct file before.

Answer (score 0):

Although it has been sometime since your post, I had just gone done the same. I download the latest dataset (which is the same as you had used).

Sounds like you didn't attach the CePa package?

```
# install CePa package from CRAN
install.packages('CePa')

# Attached require library
library(CePa)

# Load in gct file
Data <- read.gct("Path/to/file/GTEx_Analysis_2017-06-05_v8_RNASeQCv1.1.9_gene_tpm.gct")
```